# Javascript Regex to Mask or Hide numbers for a MATH Quiz i.e 1+? = 5 or 1+4 =?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, char, match

In making a basic MATH Quiz, I'd like to have something like:

Questions:

1) *Write the correct answer:*

> a) 1+? =5
>
> b) 3+? =5
>
> c) 5+? =5

2) *Write the correct answer:*

> a) 1+4 =?
>
> b) 3+? =5
>
> c) ?+0 =5

Notice that in Question Number ONE, only the `Char` after the `+` is to be Masked or Hidden.

However, in the Question Number TWO, `Char`s are to be hidden randomly.

->The Quiz will be correctly submitted by the teacher as:

> a) 1+4 =5
>
> b) 3+2 =5
>
> c) 5+0 =5

But, `REGEX` should do the Masking or Hiding of Quiz No. One after the `+` sign then  Quiz No. Two randomly.

**WHAT HAVE I TRIED?**

`str.replace(/\+\d/,"+?") //this somehow works for the number after the`+`sign`

*What Needs to be Done.*

1) Regex for the Random Masking of Numbers.

2) **[IMPORTANT]**,
In something like: 1+4=5, How to match ONLY (**bold**) **1** *+4* **=5** (Including the Equal Sign before 5)

> Notice that this is laid out that simple for explanation purpose...
>   The real Quizs are of **Algebra**, **Calculus** and **Integral by parts**.. It is
>   a solemn request by the Institution to have the Quiz with the Answers
>   Uploaded online, but somehow use *some programming magics* to hide some
>   portions of the Quiz o the Students... IT IS NOT AS SIMPLE AS *1+4=5* as given in the
>   Example. That is why *REGEX* came into picture

*Appreciation in advance*

Comment: Nothing about this seems like a job for regular expressions.

Comment: It seems that for you regex is universal hammer that can fix any problem. It is not.

Comment: It is... in most cases. As the Quiz is loaded from the Database, the plan is for it to be handled that way... Any Harm?

Comment: I think this is a typical XY problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @meagar, the question is about string parsing and replacement.  What is a better tool in JS than regex for that?

Comment: @meager @mvp When you discourage the use of REGEX in `javascript` `.replace` method what is you *Million Dollar* Suggestion?

Comment: @Steve... Your link is irrelevant to what we want. thanks anyway!

Comment: If the real questions are going to be more complex, then you're going to need different regex expressions for all of them. One way I've seen something similar done before is that the question is written like this: "Solve 5x+4y*45i=z for y, given x=blah and z=blah". In other words you  have a fixed string and array of variables, and all you have to do is show random 2 out of 3 vars. Also, if it's an online quiz, you probably shouldn't be sending answers to the browser in first place.

Comment: @MikeTrusov Thanks for the suggestion, we have a team of great programmers around here, we have thought of millions of way to make it possible and HACK FREE... The only stackOverFlow issue we have now is, to best match things based on REGEX... With the workload at hand, most of the DIRTY Jobs are done, just a few REGEX Suggestions is what we want... thank again

Comment: @ErickBest Sorry, but you do not have "great" programmers if they think regex is a good tool for this job, and yet they're unable to produce such a trivial regex themselves. Generate the three numbers randomly, and only send two of them to the client. If you actually need this to come from a database, store the *numbers* in three *numeric* columns, `3,4,7`, **not** the equation in one column string column `"3 + 4 = 7"`. There is no reason to treat this like a *string*-based problem, and then try to extract parts of the string with regex. Just *store the digits*.

Comment: Thx for ur inputs. As I mentioned, we had several Ideas laid down and we wanted to seek further inputs from *Whomever It might have concerned*. There is a SOLID reason why both **You** and **I** hv *StackOverFlow* accounts.. It is NOT to look DUMB and ask Baby-BreastFeeding Questions. *Note* that a Great Surgeon, before performing a critical operation, he seeks NOT his own Ideas but also that of others. Same as Programmers. So be rest assured that: **It may be trivial to you** , but *We Know Exactly Why We Need the REGEX*. So, if You can *HELP* do so.. if NOT.. *JUST IGNORE* ._ Respect!

Answer (score 2):

Use this regular expression to split the formula into its individual parts:

```
/(\d+)\s*\+\s*(\d+)\s*=\s*(\d+)/
```

This captures the three values.  Replace one of them with a question mark to get what you want.

```
window.mask = function()
{
    var problemText = $("#problem").val();

    var problemSplit = problemText.match(/(\d+)\s*\+\s*(\d+)\s*=\s*(\d+)/);

    $("#masked1").html("? + " + problemSplit[2] + " = " + problemSplit[3]);
    $("#masked2").html(problemSplit[1] + " + ? = " + problemSplit[3]);
    $("#masked3").html(problemSplit[1] + " + " + problemSplit[2] + " = ?");
}
```

Full example here: http://jsfiddle.net/VAhvz/2/

Comment: AMAZING...That completely solves the RANDOM Masking issue... If you don't mind, what of the [IMPORTANT] issue. (Issue No. 2)? Match: **1** *+4* **=5** ?

Comment: +1 one for a well thought approach... everyone in my office is impressed at you answer..

Comment: @ErickBest, I don't follow.  You want to match something but have a gap in the match?

Comment: Not really... is there a way to match only **1** and **=5** in 1+4=5?